# How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url?

Tags: python, url, flask

I want to detect if the request came from the `localhost:5000` or `foo.herokuapp.com` host and what path was requested.  How do I get this information about a Flask request?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

You can examine the url through several [`Request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path) fields:

> Imagine your application is listening on the following application root:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/myapplication
> ```
>
> And a user requests the following URI:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html?x=y
> ```
>
> In this case the values of the above mentioned attributes would be the following:
>
> ```
>     path             /foo/page.html
>     full_path        /foo/page.html?x=y
>     script_root      /myapplication
>     base_url         http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html
>     url              http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html?x=y
>     url_root         http://www.example.com/myapplication/
> ```

You can easily extract the host part with the appropriate splits.

An example of using this:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return request.base_url
```

Comment: new to Flask, i didn’t know where request object come from and how it works, here it is: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/

Comment: url_root returns `http://www.example.com/` not `http://www.example.com/myapplication/`

base_url returns `http://www.example.com/myapplication/`

Comment: my app route is like @app.route('/index/<int:id1>/<int:id2>') how can i guest path from request without variables. I expect **/index** in result. Which flask function to use?

Answer (score 343):

another example:

request:

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:5000/alert/dingding/test?x=y
```

then:

```
request.method:              GET
request.url:                 http://127.0.0.1:5000/alert/dingding/test?x=y
request.base_url:            http://127.0.0.1:5000/alert/dingding/test
request.url_charset:         utf-8
request.url_root:            http://127.0.0.1:5000/
str(request.url_rule):       /alert/dingding/test
request.host_url:            http://127.0.0.1:5000/
request.host:                127.0.0.1:5000
request.script_root:
request.path:                /alert/dingding/test
request.full_path:           /alert/dingding/test?x=y

request.args:                ImmutableMultiDict([('x', 'y')])
request.args.get('x'):       y
```

Comment: For people who want to use `request.full_path`, suggest to use `request.environ['RAW_URI']` instead. Because, when the actual full query path is `/alert/dingding/test`, `request.full_path` returns `/alert/dingding/test?`, an extra question mark will be added to the result, which might not be desirable.

Comment: **request.remote_addr** for 127.0.0.1

Comment: what is the different flask "host_url" "root_url" "url_root"?

Comment: request.query_string

Answer (score 14):

you should try:

```
request.url
```

It suppose to work always, even on localhost (just did it).

Comment: what is the different flask "host_url" "root_url" "url_root"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python, I would suggest by exploring the request object:

`dir(request)`

Since the object support the method **dict**:

`request.__dict__`

It can be printed or saved. I use it to log 404 codes in Flask:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    with open("./404.csv", "a") as f:
        f.write(f'{datetime.datetime.now()},{request.__dict__}\n')
    return send_file('static/images/Darknet-404-Page-Concept.png', mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: what is the different flask "host_url" "root_url" "url_root"?

Answer (score 1):

if user requests the following URI:

```
http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html?x=y
```

and the user wants y

you can use

```
request.args.get("x")
```