# Fetch requested URL - Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am working on adding error handling/logging into an API I have written using Flask-RESTful but I cannot work out how to grab the requested URL.

As an example, I am using the Python logging module to write to a log exceptions caught by Flask-RESTful's `got_request_exception`

```
app.logger.error('%s Got exception: %s', timestamp, exception)
```

I essentially wanted to log timestamp, requested URL, error message; at the moment I am just missing the requested URL since I am not sure how it is read back once passed into the API.

If someone could let me know how to pull this back out of Flask-RESTful so I can log it, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey have you checked out this other post:
[How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974730/flask-request-fields-to-get-url-path)

you can also checkout the Request context documentation:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I was reading over the Flask-RESTful documentation in particular and not the main Flask doco..

I ended up using `flask.request.url` which gave me the full URL.