# Flask: get current route

Tags: python, url, flask

In Flask, when I have several routes for the same function,
how can I know which route is used at the moment?

For example:

```
@app.route("/antitop/")
@app.route("/top/")
@requires_auth
def show_top():
    ....
```

How can I know, that now route was called using `/top/` or `/antitop/`?

**UPDATE**

I know about `request.path` I don't want use it, because the request can be rather complex, and I want repeat the routing logic in the function. I think that the solution with `url_rule` it the best one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15975041/743775 should do?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

the most 'flasky' way to check which route triggered your view is, by [`request.url_rule`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.url_rule).

```
from flask import request

rule = request.url_rule

if 'antitop' in rule.rule:
    # request by '/antitop'

elif 'top' in rule.rule:
    # request by '/top'
```

Comment: This is a good solution but consider @marcinkuzminski 's solution . I think it is more elegant.

Comment: This fails if the route is a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)
`@app.route('/user/<username>')`

Comment: @gerardw `request.url_rule.rule` is the thing. It returns `/user/<username>` as really needed.

Answer (score 121):

Simply use [`request.path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path).

```
from flask import request

...

@app.route("/antitop/")
@app.route("/top/")
@requires_auth
def show_top():
    ... request.path ...
```

Comment: Upvoting simply because you bothered with the import statement.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Agreed, so many code snippets for ANY type of code don't include import statements

Answer (score 60):

Another option is to use endpoint variable:

```
@app.route("/api/v1/generate_data", methods=['POST'], endpoint='v1')
@app.route("/api/v2/generate_data", methods=['POST'], endpoint='v2')
def generate_data():
    version = request.endpoint
    return version
```

Comment: That shows the route with dots instead of slashes. That is, 
`subunit.page` instead of `/subunit/page`

Answer (score 11):

If you want different behaviour to each route, the right thing to do is create two function handlers.

```
@app.route("/antitop/")
@requires_auth
def top():
    ...

@app.route("/top/")
@requires_auth
def anti_top():
    ...
```

In some cases, your structure makes sense. You can set values per route.

```
@app.route("/antitop/", defaults={'_route': 'antitop'})
@app.route("/top/", defaults={'_route': 'top'})
@requires_auth
def show_top(_route):
    # use _route here
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing I have to add to the answers above is that

`request.path` preserves the url parameter value(s) passed while 
`request.url_rule` gives you the url_rule you defined without the passed parameter(s)

```
@app.route("/antitop/")
@app.route("/top/")
@requires_auth
def show_top():
    request.path
    request.url_rule
    # -> both will give you "/antitop/" or "/top/"
    ....

@app.route("/antitop/<username>")
@app.route("/top/<username>")
@requires_auth
def show_top():
    request.path
    # -> gives you "/antitop/name" or ...
    request.url_rule
    # -> gives you "/antitop/<username>" or ...
    ....
```

Since you don't have any variable routes definey (*yet!*) you don't have to care but for the sake of saving you work and the headache in the future I'd still suggest using `request.path`.

**EDIT:**
Also noting that
`request.path` returns `<class 'str'>` while
`request.url_rule` returns `<class 'werkzeug.routing.rules.Rule'>`
`request.url_rule.rule` returns a `<class 'str'>` again

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that if you have a situation where it matters, you shouldn't be using the same function in the first place. Split it out into two separate handlers, which each call a common fiction for the shared code.

Comment: I think that the solution with `url_rule` is the best one, but thank you anyway and +1