# how to print the route assing to a flask function of the decorator @route

Tags: python, flask

using flask, how can i print the url path that is been assign to my function form the decorator @route with out having to do the request from internet.

example:

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    """
    the hello function
    @documentation
    :return: string
    """
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

i want to be able to do:

```
hello.__doc__ = "This is the path to the function:" +  the_full_URL_assigned_form_@app.route
```

at the end should look like this

```
hello.__doc__ = "This is the path to the function: /hello"
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498694/flask-get-current-route

Comment: thanks,  but that only happen when you run the app and call the function by internet, is there a way to get the full path of the route? with out having to run the app? and call the url?  thats what "request" pass to the application

Comment: See https://julien.danjou.info/python-ast-checking-method-declaration/