# flask restplus - get request url

Tags: python, request, flask-restplus

I'm using flask restplus and I'd like to get the request url string in order to process it within a python3 method. I cannot find how to do it neither in the documentation nor on Google. Can somebody help me?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Request fields](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.path)

```
path             /foo/page.html
full_path        /foo/page.html?x=y
script_root      /myapplication
base_url         http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html
url              http://www.example.com/myapplication/foo/page.html?x=y
url_root         http://www.example.com/myapplication/
```

[How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974730/how-do-i-get-the-different-parts-of-a-flask-requests-url)