# Flask Proxy resolve url_for

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have the following setup:

- **Main Server**:
  nginx forwarding `"https://example.com/machine1/*" -> "http://machine1/*"`
- **Machine1**:
  ngnix + uwsgi + flask mounting at `/`, e.g. `/foobar`.

That means, `https://example.com/machine1/foobar` will hit the **Machine1** as `/foobar`.
I have the mounting point `/machine1` in an variable, `NGINX_MOUNT_URL`.

Problem is, the `url_for` does not resolves that.

I tried

```
app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = NGINX_MOUNT_URL   # = "/machine1"
```

but it seems that only applies to cookie urls.

Have a simple view:

```
@app.route("/foobar")
def web_foobar():
    from flask import url_for
    return "The URL for this page is {}".format(url_for("web_foobar"))
# end def
```

So, browsing `https://example.com/machine1/foobar` (**Main Server**) will get proxied to `http://machine1/foobar` (**Machine1**) which displays `The URL for this page is /foobar`.
I need it to be `/machine1/foobar`, for linking in templates to work.

I tried the offered solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18967744/3423324, but it always ended up that I had to browse `https://example.com/machine1/machine1/foobar` to even get the page `/foobar`.

How to make `flask.url_for` aware of `APPLICATION_ROOT`?

Comment: This is an old question, but on the off chance that someone else turns up, one way that I achieved this was by passing a `url_prefix='/machine1'` when registering the service module (`register_module` was later renamed to [`register_blueprint`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/71b7c4f5f89ea5e95dc7881797ca7d3a06b97e2f/flask/app.py#L955) it seems).

Comment: I later used https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155246/3423324

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974730/how-do-i-get-the-different-parts-of-a-flask-requests-url)

The `path` and `script_root` request variables look correct for what you need.

Comment: The problem is for the template engine missing `/machine1` in front of the url when generating it with `url_for`.