# Is there a way to get the full url in flask_restful from a resource

Tags: python, rest, url, flask, flask-restful

Say I have a Resource that does not do anything but returns the url to the console

```
from app import api

class StaticFiles(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return api.url_for(self) # this only provides the resource url
```

if the request was http://localhost:5000/static code above returns /static
I am looking for http://localhost:5000/static

Usually I use requests but there is no request in resources. 
I am looking for pretty much the equivalent of `request.base_url`

Answer (score 7):

[`request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.request) is a global object which you can access by `import`ing `request` from `flask`:

```
from flask import request
from app import api

class StaticFiles(Resource):
def get(self):
    return(request.base_url)
```

There are lots of nice alternative formats of the url here, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975041/9794932) for more details.

Comment: ohhh what, 
Thanks I though request was to be used with only route decorator. What an Idiot I am, I guess it is a thread local object. You wont believe the things I tried.

Comment: @EvrenBingøl No problem, I don't think this is obvious and I also don't think this is a duplicate question as none of the other answers actually tell you how to get a hold of the `request` in the first place!