# flask request path without url

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Is there a flask function that returns request url without the variables ?

`@app.route('/index/<int:id1>/<int:id2>')`
`@app.route('/index1/<int:id1>/<int:id2>')`

For a request `/index/2/1` I expect **/index** in result
For a request `/index1/2/1` I expect **/index1** in result

I asked a function like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975041/4772933

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can add more @app.routes to match your conditions, like:

```
@app.route('/index/<int:id1>/<int:id2>') 
@app.route('/index') 
def .....
```

This way the request /index/2/1 and /index will be maped to the same function

**Edit**

I think the answer is no. But you can use **request.url_rule** inside the function to get the pattern matched for url, then should be easy to rip off the variables parts. On your case you will get the string '/index//' as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not what i asked, please see the question again, I edited it to make it more clear. What you answered is not the question.

Comment: Ow... sory about the confusion. So I think the answer is no, but with request.url_rule you can get the patern then shoul be easy to replace the variables.