# How to get just the arguments of a request in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, request

I have found this post on stackoverflow :
[How do I get the different parts of a Flask request's url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974730/how-do-i-get-the-different-parts-of-a-flask-requests-url)
We can get the different parts of the request like this :

```
With this URL :

  http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html?x=y

We can get these values :

  path             /page.html
  script_root      /myapplication
  base_url         http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html
  url              http://www.example.com/myapplication/page.html?x=y
  url_root         http://www.example.com/myapplication/
```

Is there a way to get the last part (the arguments) in a string ?
--> Get this : `?x=y`

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the named parameters from a URL using Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/how-can-i-get-the-named-parameters-from-a-url-using-flask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `request.args`

```
@app.route(...)
def some_method():
    args = request.args
    print(args)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to store all arguments in a string like this : `?x=y`

Comment: @PacCol why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to edit the url_root.

Comment: @PacCol that still doesn't explain much to me. I don't have enough context and it seems like you have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)