# How to get the specific parts of a Flask url

Tags: python, flask

i want to get the `bear` part of the http://127.0.0.1:5000/bear url

i tried methods mentioned in this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176337/14713550

```
print(request.path)
print(request.full_path)
print(str(request.url_rule))
```

they returned

```
/
/?
/
```

none of this worked, how to get the required part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add <variable_name> to your app.route
then pass it to his method as argument
like this :

```
@app.route('/<temp>')
def test(temp):
```

now you can use temp in your method as argument